Error: open EEXIST when fetching data from firebase (Node)
I recieve an error Error: open EEXIST when i am trying to get data from firebase on a node service.
I attached code below. It is in the collectionRef.get() it gives error.
It is working in local environment. I have verified the env-credentials and they seem ok.
async function fetchCollectionData(collectionName) {
  try {
    logToFile(`Initiating request to firebase for collection: ${collectionName}`);
    
    const collectionRef = db.collection(collectionName);
    const snapshot = await collectionRef.get();

    logToFile(`Request to firebase completed for collection: ${collectionName}`);

    const returnValues = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    logToFile(`Data fetched for collection: ${collectionName}`);
    return returnValues;
  } catch (error) {
    logToFile('Error fetching documents: ' + error);
    throw new Error('Server error! ' + error.message);
  }
}

I have made sure that I don't create any more instances of firebase
if (!admin.apps.length) {
  try {
    console.error('Initializing Firebase');
    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    });
    console.error('Firebase Admin SDK initialized successfully');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error initializing Firebase Admin SDK:', error);
  }
}

const db = admin.firestore();

module.exports = db;

Anyone that can help?
